# Lua Script CSV file to table

Tags: csv, file-io, lua

I'm pretty new to Lua, so I have some troubles reading data from a csv file to a table. The csv file consist of four columns. The first column is a string the other three are double values.
What I want to do is: Open the file, read in the data and process the data.
For testing I want to print the data to the screen. Later I have to open a other file, a robot programm, and pass the data to this programm.

I execute the script with the consol command `lua Script.lua`. But all I get is the error message `lua: Script.lua:22: bad argument #1 to ´format´ (number expected, got nil)`
`stack traceback: [C]: in function ´string.format´ script.lua:22: in main chunk [C]: in?`

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Edit: So I changed my Scritp a little bit. So this is my new code

```
local open = io.open

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    --if not file then return nil end
    local coordinates = {}

    for line in io.lines(path) do
    local coordinate_name, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, coordinate_z = line:match("%s*(.-),%s*(.-),%s*(.-),%s*(.-)")
    coordinates[#coordinates+1] = { coordinate_name=coordinate_name, coordinate_x = tonumber(coordinate_x), coordinate_y = tonumber(coordinate_y), coordinate_z = tonumber(coordinate_z) }
    end

    --file:close()
    return coordinates
end

local coordinates = read_file("data.csv")

for _, coordinate in ipairs(coordinates) do  -- use pairs or ipairs to iterate over tables
print(("X: %s, Y: %s, Z: %s"):format(coordinate.coordinate_x,
                                     coordinate.coordinate_y,
                                     coordinate.coordinate_z))
end

return 0;
```

Now I can execute the script, but everything printed to the screen is: `X: nil, Y: nil, Z: nil`. As far as I understand LUA, `nil` means that no values are read to the table.

Edit: The file I want to read looks like this:

```
After;-5;-5;0;
After;-2;-5;0;
After;5;-5;0;
After;5;-2;0;
After;5;5;0;
After;2;5;0;
After;-5;5;0;
After;-5;2;0;
After;-5;-5;0;
Intersects;5;-4;0
Intersects;-5;-4;0
Intersects;-5;-3;0
Intersects;5;-3;0
Intersects;5;-2;0
Intersects;-5;-2;0
```

Edit: The now updated code:

```
local open = io.open

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    --if not file then return nil end
    local coordinates = {}

    for line in io.lines(path) do
     local coordinate_name,
           coordinate_x,
           coordinate_y,
           coordinate_z = line:match("%s* (.*);%s*(.*);%s*(.*);%s*(.*);%s*(.*)")
     coordinates[#coordinates+1] = { coordinate_name = coordinate_name, coordinate_x = tonumber(coordinate_x), coordinate_y = tonumber(coordinate_y), coordinate_z = tonumber(coordinate_z) }
    print(("X: %s Y: %4f Z: %s"):format(coordinates.coordinate_x,
                                     coordinates.coordinate_y,
                                     coordinates.coordinate_z))
    end

    for _, coordinate in ipairs(coordinates) do
        print(coordinates.coordinate_x, coordinates.coordinate_z, coordinates.coordinate_z)
    end

    file:close()

    return coordinates
end

local coordinates = read_file("data.csv")
    for _, coordinates in ipairs(coordinates) do  -- use pairs or ipairs to iterate over tables
        print(("X: %s, Y: %s, Z: %s"):format(coordinates.coordinate_x,
                                         coordinates.coordinate_y,
                                         coordinates.coordinate_z))
    end

 return 0;
```

I'm using Lua 5.3.3 for Windows, the script is writen in LuaEdit and called by the line `lua Script.lua`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `(.*)` in your pattern instead of `(.-)`. Per the [docs](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#6.4.1), `-` will match the shortest pattern, which seems to bug out for the z coordinate in my testing:

*Updated to match the file format posted*

```
    local coordinate_name,
          coordinate_x,
          coordinate_y,
          coordinate_z = line:match("([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)")
```

The `tonumber` will handle the space trimming for you and you don't seem to be using coordinate_name anywhere. There are plenty of [string trim implementations](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringTrim) you can choose from if you need to trim the coordinate_name variable later on.

Full script for reference.

```
local open = io.open

local function read_file(path)
    local file = open(path, "r") -- r read mode and b binary mode
    --if not file then return nil end
    local coordinates = {}

    for line in io.lines(path) do
        local coordinate_name,
        coordinate_x,
        coordinate_y,
        coordinate_z = line:match("([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)")
        coordinates[#coordinates+1] = { coordinate_name = coordinate_name, coordinate_x = tonumber(coordinate_x), coordinate_y = tonumber(coordinate_y), coordinate_z = tonumber(coordinate_z) }
    end

    file:close()

    return coordinates
end

local coordinates = read_file("data.csv")
for _, coordinate in ipairs(coordinates) do  -- use pairs or ipairs to iterate over tables
    print(("X: %s, Y: %s, Z: %s"):format(coordinate.coordinate_x,
    coordinate.coordinate_y,
    coordinate.coordinate_z))
end

return 0;
```

Comment: I just tried your pattern to read the csv file. But still all printed to the console window is: `X: nil, Y. nil, Z: nil`. Is there a way to test if the read function works and test the print seperatly. Maybe the read function works, but my print function is wrong.

Comment: Your print function works fine for me. Perhaps there's something wrong with your file or maybe it's not reading it at all because it's not in the same folder. Try printing out the line variable in your read_file loop and see if any output shows up and to double-check that the contents are in the right format.

Comment: I copied the print line into the loop `for line in io.lines(path) do` and still get the nil as answer. I also checked that the file is in the same folder as the lua script and that the command line is opened in the same folder. I also edited my question so you see what the file looks like.

Comment: Ah, there's your problem. Your fields are separated by semicolons, not commas. Try `line:match("%s*(.*);%s*(.*);%s*(.*);%s*(.*)")`

Comment: I changed the line you suggested, but still nothing is printed to screen. But I still have a question. If I'm reading in the coordinates as a string and than convert these coordinates to numbers by the command `tonumber`, is it correct to print it with `%s`? Wouldn't `%d` be better, like in C?

Comment: Post your updated file? What version of lua are you running when you run `lua -v` on the command line? The latter *shouldn't* matter, but just in case. Also, when you added the print to the read_file loop, did you just do `print(line)`? This is just to sanity check that you're actually reading the file.

Comment: `line:match("([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*);([^;]*)"))` should fix it. The trailing semicolons are probably causing tonumber to fail. %d could work but you have to account for the negative numbers as well as it won't catch the minus sign. You'll have to adjust your pattern to accommodate if you go that route.

Comment: I edited the `line:match` and added `print(line)` now I get an correct output, but when my print function is ecexuted again `nil` is printed

Comment: I updated my post with my complete script file. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Did you run my code exactly as is from the command line while inside the same folder where both your data and script is located? If so, then I'm stumped. I'm using the same lua version as you are on windows and it's parsing your file just fine.

Comment: Yes, I just made a new file, named it Script2.lua saved it in the same directory as the csv file and started it.

Comment: All I can suggest at this point is to print each line and coordinate variable before the tonumber call and after in your line match loop. Example: `print(line)` then `print(coordinate_name, coordinate_x, coordinate_y, coordinate_z)` and then `print(coordinate_name, tonumber(coordinate_x), tonumber(coordinate_y), tonumber(coordinate_z))` If something turns into nil, then some character was not accounted for in the match and you need to look at your file again. The file snippet you posted works, but perhaps something breaks the pattern later on that wasn't accounted for.

Comment: Just to add, here's an [online demo](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_lua_online.php?PID=0Bw_CjBb95KQMbURGbi1MN243aVE) that illustrates it works:

Comment: I don't know what I changed, but I just tested your code after my lunch break again, and now it seems to work. Hate it when that happens. Tank you for everything, you did. Just one question: If I want to access one element of the table, what would be the best way to do so?

Comment: No problem. Tables can be treated like arrays, especially in your example since the keys are in numeric order, so there's nothing stopping you from writing something like `coordinates[1].coordinate_name` if you want the name associated with the first coordinate for instance. A lot of tutorials emphasize using pairs/ipairs to loop, but single access can work just as well if you need it.